# Python read-modify-write line

Tags: python

I'm doing some editing on a file line by line

what i would like to do is the following
i have a line and i want to use delimiter to split it and take the first argument after delimiter which is space.

```
for line in file1:
  line = line.strip();
  new = line.split(" ")[1]+"\n";      
  file2.write(new);
file2.close();
file2  = open("temp.hex",'r');


for line in file2:
```

as you can see the way i do it as split the line by delimiter and write it
to new file. then i want to do some more editing so i must close and reopen file to iterate it line by line

my questions are
1. can i modify the line originally on file1?
2. do i must close file2 before i scan it again line by line?

Thanks allot, Jonathan

Comment: All those semicolons...

Comment: Why scan file2 ? Do the processing you want and then write the result

Comment: TigerhawkT3 what about them ? (new to python)

Comment: Tasos Vogiatzoglou, 
1.lets say this i want to work.
2. can i modify original file?

Comment: Python don't need semicolons

Comment: Thanks for the semiclons comment..

Answer (score 1):

FYI you don't need semicolons in Python. They don't harm your code, but they aren't necessary either.

You can combine multiple `open` calls with the `with` statement which will also close the files implicitly after program exits:

```
with open('a', 'r') as file1 and open('b', 'w') as file2:
    for line in file1:
        line = line.strip()
        new = line.split(" ")[1]+"\n"
        file2.write(new)

        # do additional editing
```

Comment: Nitpick: they aren't closed when the program ends, they are closed when the code exits the `with` block.

Answer (score 0):

Because the reputation limit on comments i need to write here to answer to xPino
from ILostMySpoon answer:

```
with open('a', 'r') as file1 and open('b', 'w') as file2:
    for line in file1:
        line = line.strip()
        new = line.split(" ")[1]+"\n"
        file2.write(new)

    # do additional editing
```

1. opening a with only read atr as file1 [ file1 = fopen('filename','attributes') ] same with file2
2. for every line in the file1
3. line = line.strip() remove the whitespace in the end of the line
4. new = the line is splitted everywhere theres a whitespace and added the \n in the end.
5. write out new into the file 2.

Its will rewrite the file 2 everytime if im right i would use append in file2